# cssSelector for specific url

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am new to selenium. for example, i have the below html:

```
<div class = "abc">
  <a href = ".com">
</div>

<div class = "abc">
  <a href = ".org">
</div>

<div class = "abc">
  <a href = ".com">
</div>
```

now i want to get all those elements, which have href finished with .com.

for this i use:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div.classname>a));
```

but it select all the elements with div>a

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
div.abc >a[href$=".com"]
```

this will select only those which ends with .com

details are in this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp